# Crossfade slideshow with vanilla js between layers of separate containers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```
var current = 0,
    slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slider");

setInterval(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }
  current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;
  slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
}, 4000);
```

which basically iterates through my HTML making a crossfade between every layer with a "slider" class, in order: slides[0], slides[1](https://codepen.io/mrmerrick/pen/NbwgYo), etc, with a pause of 4 seconds between each crossfade. And then cycles from the beginning.

Now I want to expand this function to apply to 3 different containers, each with a varying number of layers inside, and I want the 3 crossfades to start at the same time and run non sequentially. By this I mean that I don't want it to go like this:

```
group01[0] -> group01[1] -> group01[2] -> group02[0] -> group02[1] -> group02[2]
```

I want it to go like this:

```
group01[0] -> group01[1] -> group01[2]
group02[0] -> group02[1] -> group02[2] -> group02[3]
group03[0] -> group03[1]
```

*(so, all start at the same time, some containers have more layers than others - and then cycle from the beginning)*

I tried turning the code into a reusable function where I give the layer group as an argument, but had no luck and the console doesn't throw any error:

```
var group01 = document.getElementById("group01").getElementsByClassName("slider");
var group02 = document.getElementById("group02").getElementsByClassName("slider");
var group03 = document.getElementById("group03").getElementsByClassName("slider");

var timer01 = setInterval(doSlider(group01), 4000);
var timer02 = setInterval(doSlider(group02), 4000);
var timer03 = setInterval(doSlider(group03), 4000);

function doSlider(slides) {
    var current = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }
  current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;
  slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT - Complete code (Pen here!: https://codepen.io/mrmerrick/pen/NbwgYo)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div id="group01" class="sliderWrapper">
    <div class="slider slider01">
    </div>
    <div class="slider slider02">
    </div>
    <div class="slider slider03">
    </div>
    <div class="slider slider04">
    </div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/3L2LSoT.png" alt="transparent placeholder">
  </div>

  <div id="group02" class="sliderWrapper">
    <div class="slider slider01">
    </div>
    <div class="slider slider02">
    </div>
    <div class="slider slider03">
    </div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/3L2LSoT.png" alt="transparent placeholder">
  </div>

  <div id="group03" class="sliderWrapper">
    <div class="slider slider01">
    </div>
    <div class="slider slider02">
    </div>
    <div class="slider slider03">
    </div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/3L2LSoT.png" alt="transparent placeholder">
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

    .sliderWrapper  {
            position: relative;
            width: 90%;
            height: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }

            .sliderWrapper img {
                width: 100%;
            }

            .slider {
                position: absolute;

                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;

                transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
            }

            .slider + .slider {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            #group01 .slider01 {
                background: url(http://placehold.it/792x1599?text=group01+slide01) center center no-repeat;
                background-size: contain;
                z-index: 5;
            }

            #group01 .slider02 {
                background: url(http://placehold.it/792x1599?text=group01+slide02) center center no-repeat;
                background-size: contain;
                z-index: 6;
            }

            #group01 .slider03 {
                background: url(http://placehold.it/792x1599?text=group01+slide03) center center no-repeat;
                background-size: contain;
                z-index: 7;
            }

            #group01 .slider04 {
                background: url(http://placehold.it/792x1599?text=group01+slide04) center center no-repeat;
                background-size: contain;
                z-index: 8;
            }

            #group02 .slider01 {
                background: url(http://placehold.it/792x1599?text=group02+slide01) center center no-repeat;
                background-size: contain;
                z-index: 9;
            }

            #group02 .slider02 {
                background: url(http://placehold.it/792x1599?text=group02+slide02) center center no-repeat;
                background-size: contain;
                z-index: 10;
            }

            #group02 .slider03 {
                background: url(http://placehold.it/792x1599?text=group02+slide03) center center no-repeat;
                background-size: contain;
                z-index: 11;
            }


            #group03 .slider01 {
                background: url(http://placehold.it/792x1599?text=group03+slide01) center center no-repeat;
                background-size: contain;
                z-index: 12;
            }

            #group03 .slider02 {
                background: url(http://placehold.it/792x1599?text=group03+slide02) center center no-repeat;
                background-size: contain;
                z-index: 13;
            }

            #group03 .slider03 {
                background: url(http://placehold.it/792x1599?text=group03+slide03) center center no-repeat;
                background-size: contain;
                z-index: 14;
            }
```

**JS**

```
var group01 = document.getElementById("group01").getElementsByClassName("slider");
var group02 = document.getElementById("group02").getElementsByClassName("slider");
var group03 = document.getElementById("group03").getElementsByClassName("slider");

var timer01 = setInterval(doSlider(group01), 4000);
var timer02 = setInterval(doSlider(group02), 4000);
var timer03 = setInterval(doSlider(group03), 4000);

function doSlider(slides) {
    var current = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }
  current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;
  slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
};
```

Comment: Need HTML, CSS, and JS in a [mcve]

Comment: My bad, sorry! Just edited my question with a complete example and a link to codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `current` to `0` every time `setInterval` calls `doSlider`, which means you will only ever see `slides[1]`. You should close over `current` and `slides` and then increment `current` every time it is called by `setInterval`. Like so:

```
var group01 = document.getElementById("section01").getElementsByClassName("slider");
var group02 = document.getElementById("section02").getElementsByClassName("slider");
var group03 = document.getElementById("section03").getElementsByClassName("slider");

var slider01 = doSlider(group01);
var slider02 = doSlider(group02);
var slider03 = doSlider(group03);

var timer01 = setInterval(slider01.next, 4000);
var timer02 = setInterval(slider02.next, 4000);
var timer03 = setInterval(slider03.next, 4000);

function doSlider(slides) {
  var current = 0;
  slides[0].style.opacity = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }
  return {
    next: function() {
      slides[current].style.opacity = 0;
      current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;
      slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
    }
  };
}
```

(Hopefully this works or at least leads you to the right answer. I didn't test it).

Comment: Thanks for answering! The fact that setInterval calls the function every 4 seconds, obviously resetting the counter every time, went over the top of my head. Your solution works for the most part, but it doesn't cycle, gets stuck at the last slide. Will test more thoroughly, I think I may be able to reach my desired output thanks to your code. I'll update with the result :)

Comment: Just ten minutes ago I reached a different solution to yours, by using objects with the layer groups inside and storing a "current" var on each of them in order to track each group separately. But just tried your latest edit and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help!